# Find minimal set of progressions which intersections, unions or negations covers given set

Tags: co.combinatorics, algorithms

Given an integer $N$ and a set of integers in $[1; N]$. Find a minimal set of integer arithmetical progressions such as given set can be covered using operations $A \cap B$, $A \cup B$ and $\overline A$ and the coverage has no excess points in $(-\infty; N]$.

Am I right assuming that this problem can be reduced to the [set cover problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem)? I couldn't come up with a strict proof for some reason yet.

Comment: The question is unclear. Isn't $1,2,\dots,N$ an integer arithmetical progression that covers $[1,N]$ all by itself? What is an "excess point"?

Comment: Sorry, I meant that every point in given set is in range $[1, N]$. Excess point is a number which is covered but does not belong to the given set.

Comment: OK, I mostly understand now, though I'm not sure I understand the switch between $[1;N]$ and $(-\infty;N]$.

Comment: The idea behind using $-\infty$ is that progressions have to start in $[1;N]$. This is probably unnecessary condition though. Obviously an intersection of progressions gives another progression and any combination can be presented as unions of intersections of progressions or their negations, but I can't make a step further.

Comment: What if you take a set with no 3-term APs? There are known examples when such a set is fairly big.